# how to detect arabic sign in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to search in QURAN with query in Mysql but there is no difference between 'وُ' and 'وَ' and 'وْ' or something like this in search time, for example if I search 'وُ' the results are all type of 'و'.
my table collection is utf8_unicode_ci.

Answer (score 1):

To read ,write and sort Arabic text in MySQL database using PHP correctly, make sure that:

- MySQL charset: `UTF-8 Unicode` (`utf8`)
- MySQL connection collation: `utf8_general_ci`
- your database and table collations are set to: `utf8_general_ci` or `utf8_unicode_ci`

Then, add this code in your PHP script when you connect to database:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

For more details: [example here](http://www.adviesenzo.nl/examples/php_mysql_charset_fix/)

Comment: all right! but I want to search in phpmyadmin and there is no difference between 'وُ' and 'وَ' and 'وْ' and my data base is utf8_unicode_ci